# Creating a list from while loop and store in one line

Tags: python

**Hello** *im trying to make a password generator and I dont know how to create a list in one line*

**sorry for bad explanation, here is some photos/codes that will help to understand**

```py
if symbols:
    i = 1
    while i < 10:
        symbols = random.choice(password_dictionary["symbols"])
        i += 1
```

**So this is my code for the while loop and the input is printed columns like this :**

```
(
!
$
{
(
:
(
]
[
```

**Is there any way I could make it print in one line and store in somewhere just like this**

random_symbols = `(!${(:(][`

Comment: Checkout: [Python password generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212164/python-password-generator)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a list of symbols in one line

```
random_symbols = [random.choice(password_dictionary["symbols"]) for _ in range(10)]
```

This code combines all chars in random symbols and prints them in one line:

```
password = "".join(symbols)

print(password)
```

Comment: both statements can be combined into one liner. `random_symbols = ''.join([random.choice(password_dictionary["symbols"]) for _ in range(1, 10)])`

Comment: yea but to make it more readable it is better to keep them seperated

Comment: I agree but op specifically mentioned one-liner.

Comment: yea the one-liner for the list creation :) but i can edit so your answer gets its credit too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values to a string like so:

```
output = "".join([random.choice(password_dictionary["symbols"]) for _ in range(10)])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
(!${(:(][
```

Or to a list like this:

```
output = [random.choice(password_dictionary["symbols"]) for _ in range(10)]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
$!!{([:][
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want a one-liner then you can use python list comprehension for this.

```
random_symbols = "".join(
    [random.choice(password_dictionary["symbols"]) for _ in range(1, 10)]
)
print(random_symbols)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could store the data in a list where each character is a seperate element in the list.

Then you can use the join function to get a string of the list.

```
password_as_list = []
```

After each iteration in the loop the symbol is appended

```
password_as_list.append(symbols)
```

join converts the list into one fluent string

```
password = ''.join(password_as_list)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).